# How to Install openFire with out opening the web gui admin console?

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire

Open fire installation is straight forward [which is explained here really well](http://mindbowser.com/blog/openfire-installation-and-database-configuration/) .

Is there is any command line tool to complete the installation process?

Any configuration files which needs to be changed to complete the installation process with out accessing the admin console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Openfire it's installable without admin console by

- Insert rows in ofProperty table of database
- Configue openfire.xml and security.xml under /conf directory
- copy plugin's jar in /plugins directory
- for each plugin previusly copied, extract the files inside (=> unjar/unzip) creating a folder with the same name of the plugin*

*Example: to install jabber search, get search.jar and copy under /plugins directory.
Then unjar search.jar in a folder named "search" => you'll obtain a structure like this:

```
<openfire_dir>
|
plugins
    |- search.jar
    |- search
          |- search.jar exploded
```

I suggest you to install in a develop envrinoment and then export the values.

Be carefull:

1. You'll have to configure database's drivers (both in xml
   and in database)
2. name of Openfire (in database you'll have 2 entries, 1 is the name,
   2nd it's the list of JID of administrators, so admin@myserverdevelop
   must to be changed in admin@myserverproduction)
3. If you want to change the password of database' user, you'll have to remove the "ecryption" from security.xml and set name/password pair with attribute encrypt="false" in openfire.xml. Only add the attribute will not works.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I will verify and will accept your answer :), as first adding the properties in the properties in the conf/openfire.xml are lost on openfire restart.

Comment: by the way, if you lose your entry in XML just change the installation directory of openfire (maybe you don't have permissions to write in and that's why you lose settings)

Comment: I forget to explain plugins part, added @forum.test17 . BTW, to me appears strange about misleading this question, probably that was me to answer also in openfire community forum...

Comment: Thanks for the adding the plugins part :)